# Как отловить контролы qt приложения?

Tags: c#, qt, button, handle

Необходимо программно нажать на кнопку qt приложения,которое открыто без отображения окна. Как отловить кнопку для дальнейшего взаимодействия?

Comment: Нажиматься кнопка должна с помощью windows приложения на C#.

Comment: Добавите конкретный пример кода, где у вас проблема,

Comment: Что значит "открыто без отображения окна"? Специальный режим работы который поддерживает это приложение, или специальный режим работы приложений, который поддерживает операционная система?

Comment: qt приложение будет запускаться с помощью батника в скрытом режиме.

Comment: Я может чего не знаю, но по моему это не возможно без тяжелых хаков или модификации самого приложения